# Update multiple records at once with PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008, forms, http-post

I am trying to update multiple records within an HTML form, but it isn't writing any data back, and I am getting no errors.

The table already exists and has half of the data already in it so I need to update records, not insert.

This is my form:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php" id="price-increase"></form>
<div class="x_panel">
<div class="x_content">             
    <table id="tablePrice" class="display table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Item Code</th>
                <th>Customer Increase</th>
                <th>New Invoice</th>
                <th>New Net</th>
                <th>New Matrix</th>
                <th>New Band A</th>
                <th>Incresed Date</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php while($res = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $res['ItemCode'];?></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="customerIncrease" id="customerIncrease" class="form-control" value="<?php if(!empty($res['CustomerIncrease'])){echo $res['CustomerIncrease'];}?>">
                    </td>
                     <td>
                        <input type="text" name="newInvoice" id="newInvoice" class="form-control" value="<?php if(!empty($res['NewInvoice'])){echo $res['NewInvoice'];}?>">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="newNet" id="newNet" class="form-control" value="<?php if(!empty($res['NewNet'])){echo $res['NewNet'];}?>">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="newMX" id="newMX" class="form-control" value="<?php if(!empty($res['NewMX'])){echo $res['NewMX'];}?>">
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $res['NewBandA'];?>
                        <input type="text" name="newBandA" id="newBandA" class="form-control" value="<?php if(!empty($res['NewBandA'])){echo $res['NewBandA'];}?>">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="increaseDate" name="increaseDate" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" required="required" type="text" value="<?php if(!empty($res['IncreaseDate'])){echo $res['IncreaseDate'];}?>">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </tbody>                        
    </table>    
    <a href="test.php">
        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" value="Submit">Save</button>
    </a>
</div>
```

This is my PHP:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $itemCode = (isset($_POST['ItemCode']) && !empty($_POST['ItemCode']))?$_POST['ItemCode'] : NULL;
    $customerIncrease = (isset($_POST['CustomerIncrease']) && !empty($_POST['CustomerIncrease']))?$_POST['CustomerIncrease'] : NULL;
    $newInvoice = (isset($_POST['NewInvoice']) && !empty($_POST['NewInvoice']))?$_POST['NewInvoice'] : NULL;
    $newNet = (isset($_POST['NewNet']) && !empty($_POST['NewNet']))?$_POST['NewNet'] : NULL;
    $newMX = (isset($_POST['NewMX']) && !empty($_POST['NewMX']))?$_POST['NewMX'] : NULL;
    $newBandA = (isset($_POST['NewBandA']) && !empty($_POST['NewBandA']))?$_POST['NewBandA'] : NULL;
    $increaseDate = (isset($_POST['IncreaseDate']) && !empty($_POST['IncreaseDate']))?$_POST['IncreaseDate'] : NULL;
    $processed = (isset($_POST['Processed']) && !empty($_POST['Processed']))?$_POST['Processed'] : NULL;

    $query = "  UPDATE po_SupplierPriceIncrease 

                SET CustomerIncrease = '$customerIncrease',
                    NewInvoice = '$newInvoice',
                    NewNet = '$newNet',
                    NewMX = '$newMX',
                    NewBandA = '$newBandA',
                    IncreaseDate = '$increaseDate',
                    Processed = '$processed'

                WHERE ItemCode = '$itemCode';
                    ";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($sapconn2, $query);
    sqlsrv_execute($stmt);   
    return $stmt;

    }
?>
```

Like I said, it won't update and it has no errors. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You are wide open to SQL Injection attacks and should use Prepared Statements instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not even escaping the user inputs. Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple flaws with the HTML form:

1. The form tag is immediately closed after it is opened - i.e.`<form id="tablePrice"...></form>`
   So move the closing tag (i.e. `</form>`) after any form elements that need to be submitted.
2. The *ItemCode* is not being submitted with the form. Create an input (perhaps it should be hidden and/or read-only) to submit that value - e.g. `<td><input type="Number" name="ItemCode" value="<?php echo $res['ItemCode'];?>" readonly /></td>`
3. Because an [input element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) can have no permitted content, they are self closing, so add the (forward) slash (i.e. `/`) to the end of each input tag -`<input type="text" name="NewMX" id="newMX" class="form-control" value="<?php if(!empty($res['NewMX'])){echo $res['NewMX'];}?>" />`

As far as being able to *Update multiple records at once* (per your question title), in order to do that, you would likely need to update your `UPDATE` SQL query to have some logic based on the ItemCode value (e.g. with [`CASE` statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)). And the form fields would need to be in array format (e.g. `CustomerIncrease[]`) or have unique names (perhaps with the ItemCode value appended -e.g. `CustomerIncrease_1`) in order to associate various values with the row to update.

And [as @Magnus Eriksson suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104684/update-multiple-records-at-once-with-php/41107593#comment69413829_41104684), you should use a prepared statement (with bound parameters) to avoid SQL injection attacks. So you could simplify your PHP code like the example below, utilizing the 3rd parameter of [`sqlsrv_prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php) - an array of parameters.

> **params**: 
> An array specifying parameter information when executing a parameterized query.

Note: you would need to update the case of the *name* attributes on the `<input>` fields to match the names in $fields - e.g. `<input type="text" name="NewNet"...>`

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['ItemCode']) {
    //these fields should match the name attribute of the inputs in the form
    $fields = ['CustomerIncrease', 'NewInvoice', 'NewNet', 'NewMX', 'NewBandA', 'IncreaseDate'];
    $params = [];
    $setFields = [];
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (!empty($_POST[$field])) {
            $params[] = $_POST[$field];
            $setFields[] = $field.' = ?';
        } else {
            $setFields[] = $field.' = NULL';
        }
    }

    //optional : add ProcessedDate to setFields with value from GetDate()?
    $params[] = $_POST['ItemCode'];

    $query = "  UPDATE po_SupplierPriceIncrease 
            SET " . implode(', ', $setFields) . "
            WHERE ItemCode = ?";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($connection, $query,$params);
    sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `ItemCode` in the html code, which makes `$itemCode` null.

So, this part of your query:

```
WHERE ItemCode = '$itemCode'
```

becomes:

```
WHERE ItemCode = ''
```

Which is a correct query hence no errors, although it updates no record.